# compare whether two python files result in same byte code (are code wise identical)

Tags: python, comparison, bytecode, pyc

We're doing some code cleanup.
The cleanup is only about formatting (if an issue, then let's even assume, that line numbers don't change, though ideally I'd like to ignore also line number changes)

In order to be sure, that there is no accidental code change I'd like to find a simple / fast way to compare the two source codes.

So let's assume, that I have `file1.py` and `file2.py`

what is working is to use
`py_compile.compile(filename)` to create .pyc files and then use
`uncompyle6 pycfile`, then strip off comments and compare the results,
But this is overkill and very slow.

Another approach I imagined is to copy
`file1.py` for example to `file.py`,
use `py_compile.compile("file.py")` and save the .pyc file

then copy `file2.py` for example to `file.py` and use
use `py_compile.compile("file.py")` and save the .pyc file
and finally compare both generated .pyc files

Would this work reliably with all (current) versions >= python 3.6

If I remember at least for python2 the pyc files could contain time stamps or absolute paths, that could make the comparison fail. (at least if the generation of the pyc file was run on two different machines)

Is there a clean way to compare the byte code of py2 files?

As bonus feature (if possible) I'd like to create a hash for each byte code, that I could store for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try using Python's internal [`compile` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=compile#compile), which can compile from string (read in from a file in your case). For example, compiling and comparing the resulting code objects from two equivalent programs and one almost equivalent program and then just for demo purposes (something you would *not* want to do) executing a couple of the code objects:

```py
import hashlib
import marshal
​
​
def compute_hash(code):
    code_bytes = marshal.dumps(code)
    code_hash = hashlib.sha1(code_bytes).hexdigest()
    return code_hash
​
​
source1 = """x = 3
y = 4
z = x * y
print(z)
"""
source2 = "x=3;y=4;z=x*y;print(z)"
​
source3 = "a=3;y=4;z=a*y;print(z)"
​
obj1 = compile(source=source1, filename='<string>', mode='exec', dont_inherit=1)
obj2 = compile(source=source2, filename='<string>', mode='exec', dont_inherit=1)
obj3 = compile(source=source3, filename='<string>', mode='exec', dont_inherit=1)
​
print(obj1 == obj2)
print(obj1 == obj3)
​
exec(obj1)
exec(obj3)
print(compute_hash(obj1))
```

Prints:

```
True
False
12
12
48632a1b64357e9d09d19e765d3dc6863ee67ab9
```

**This will save you from having to copying py files, creating pyc files, comparing pyc files, etc.**

**Note:**

The `compute_hash` function is if you need a hash function that is repeatable, i.e. returns the same value repeatedly for the same code object when computed in successive program runs.

Comment: Good idea. will try this. Didn't even think that that the result of compile might be comparable.

However I'm afraid, that the hash of `obj1` will not be the same as hash of `obj2`
The idea of hashing was that I could just compare hashes or compare hashes of two py / pyc files on two different machines to see whether they are yielding identical byte code, but I will already check, whether compile works fine.

Comment: The two sources are not accessible from the same machine? That would greatly simplify matters. But I would think if you are running two identical Python interpreters, i.e. the same exact release, the code produced will be identical and thus the two hashes have to be the same.

Comment: I have multiple use cases.
for what I try to do now. same machine is completely acceptable

However  hashes are randomized and don't really tell you something bout the contents,

Try for example to call 
`python3 -c 'print(hash("hello new world"))'` twice.

or try to print the hash of an object and change some value of the object and reprint the hash.

Comment: Then the hashes are guaranteed to be the same or else the `==` test would fail between the two code objects.

Comment: but in case of the code object at least for the small examples your're right.
Hashes are identical for both code objects (if executed within the same process)
So I coul dnot store it for future reference, but that's no issue for what I try to do at the moment

Comment: Perhaps you could add following  to your answer?

if you need a unique inter process hash, then following would work:

`import hashlib` then  `import marshall` then `obj1  = compile(source=source1, filename='<string>', mode='exec', dont_inherit=1)` then `code_bytes1 = marshal.dumps(obj1)` then `code_hash1 = hashlib.sha1(code_bytes1).hexdigest()`

Comment: if you don't have time or if you don't want to change your answer, just tell me.
I will still accept your answer.
and might just add an alternative answer for a hashable solution.

Not everybody needs something, that's predictible hashes when run on two processes or even machines

Comment: I am *willing* to update my answer if you would explain why this hash computation would be an improvement over what my answer has. Using this method will only produce the same hash values if you start out with the equal code objects. Are you worried that somehow `hash(obj1)` will produce different results on different machines even though the two code objects are identical (if they aren't identical, your new hash function won't work either). You can accept the answer -- I've been known to modify answers after they have been accepted if I have an improvement or  a new insight.

Comment: change your program to print out the hash and call it multiple times.
You will see, that the hash is not a fixed value (at least for my tests)
Which means, you could not calculate the hash on one machine and on another and detect that the code on both machines is identical.

In fact it doesn't even work on the same machine with two different processes.

Up to my knowledge a python hash is not a fixed values..

My approach converts the code object into bytes and calculates an sha1 hash.
the marshalled bytes don't seem to change between different runs

Comment: Right you are! The answer has been updated.

Comment: posted another question, which is not the same, but similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66141364/check-that-two-pyc-files-contain-the-same-code

Answer (score 0):

Might be not the desired answer - but why dont you use a diff tool to compare the if the files are changed?
https://linuxhandbook.com/diff-command/

And if the files are changed use a mergetool like meld to compare the changes http://meldmerge.org/

Comment: `diff` can't really be used, as following lines would result in the same byte code.

`a = "hello"`  vs. `a = u"hello"` vs. `a    =     "hello"`    vs. `a = "hello" #and a comment`

The idea is to render the code more readable, more uniform, to remove python2 artifacts like the `u` prefix for unicode strigns / etc. but to be sure one didn't replace by accident the wrong `u"`  as for example in.

`a = u"I can see u"`m which xould become `a = "i can see u"`, but which should not become `a = "i can see "`

Comment: I changed the question title to make my intention (hopefully) clearer