# Check if two .pyc files (compiled with same python version) contain the same code

Tags: python, comparison, pyc

The question is similar, but not identical to [compare whether two python files result in same byte code (are code wise identical)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66135730/compare-whether-two-python-files-result-in-same-byte-code-are-code-wise-identic).

In fact I have a solution, but It's not that elegant:

Let's assume I have some `.pyc` file created on one machine and some `.pyc` file created on another machine.
I assume the `.pyc` files are created with the same version of python.

Otherwise I had to use a much slower tool like `uncompyle6`.

How can I verify, that both contain the same byte code?

I have two problems which will be mentioned below:

1. Read in `.pyc` file:

   No problem here.

   ```
   import marshal
   import hashlib

   def calc_pyc_hash(pyc_fname):
       with open(pyc_fname, "rb") as fin:
           pyc_data = fin.read()
   ```
2. **Problem 1:** Strip header bytes and extract code object
   This is a problem, as the amount of bytes to strip seems to depend on the python version.
   Is there an easy way to get the right value programmatically?

   My workaround: (code is still part of `calc_pyc_hash`)

   ```
      for offs in range(8, 20):
          try:
              code = marshal.loads(pyc_data[offs:])
              print("offset of %d bytes for %s" % (offs, sys.version_info))
              break
          except Exception:
              pass
      else:
          print("no solution found")    sys.exit(-1)
   ```
3. **Problem 2:** How to ignore the field `co_filename`.
   The code object has a field `co_filename`, which is the name of the compiled python file.
   This name may unfortunately be a file name with an absolute path, which may vary depending on where and how the `.pyc` file has been created. The only way that I found is following (code is still part of `calc_pyc_hash`):

   ```
       code_bytes = []
       fields = [name for name in dir(code) if name.startswith("co_") 
                 and name != "co_filename"]
       for fieldname in fields:
           code_bytes.append(marshal.dumps(getattr(code, fieldname)))

       code_bytes = b"".join(code_bytes)
       hashval = hashlib.sha1(code_bytes).hexdigest()
       return hashval
   ```

What I consider to be not really elegant is, that I have to guess the amount of header bytes to
skip and that I have to strip off the filename and concatenate the data of the other fields.

Does anyone have a more elegant solution?

Comment: If you read my comment, which I have deleted: never mind -- I was wrong about able to unmarshall with two offsets. However, you do have an indentation error in your workaround code. In theory there is no upper limit to how large the header could be in the future and for any given release of the Python interpreter the header size is known (16 for my Python 3.8.5). I would just use a hard-coded value and know that when you change to a new version (how often do you do that?), to see if you need to update the header size. But that's me. Otherwise, I haven't had a chance to look at this in detail.

Comment: Looks okay to me. Of course, if you change even a docstring within the file, the hash will change. You could also try to marshal *all* fields except `co_filename` and ignore `ValueError` exceptions for those fields that cannot be marshalled.

Comment: @Booboo What is the indentation error?
You mean the `else:`   or do you mean, that the code  of step2 and step3 should be indented by four more characters?

Comment: @Booboo I tried to fix indentation. The `else:` is correctly indented it would be executed if no offset was found.

And yes you're right. changes in doc strings would be flagged as a difference, which is fine with me in my context.

Concerning hard-coding the offset:
Same code executed on multiple machines with multiple py versions. what I could do is create a lookup, that's using `sys.version_info[:2]` as a key.

concerning,which fields to marshal. I'm not sure, but think that only the field names starting with `co_` are related to the byte code. but I'm not an expert about byte code.

Comment: Something for you to think about: Let's say your project has been compiled with 3.8 and now your interpreter has been upgraded to 3.9. The header length is still 16 bytes but until the pyc file is regenerated, which normally only happens when the corresponding source is imported, you will not be able to unmarshall the code. Some of your pyc files might be 3.8 and others 3.9. And  top-level programs (main programs) would not have pyc files at all. In that situation do you plan on manually compiling every source program?

Comment: Also, same code on different machines with different Python versions might have different hash values just because the compiler generates different code for the same source.

Comment: @Booboo in my context I just have to compare .py files on two different machines, but I  know, that the 2 machines, that I compare will have the same python version. but good and valid points for anybody else reading this question

Comment: @Booboo I changed the title to: "Check if two .pyc files (compiled with same python version) contain the same code"

to make this more obvious for others